# Forward-backward filtering with exponential moving average

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, signal-processing

I'm trying to smooth a signal using exponential weighted moving average using both past and future values.

I have tried the built-in version of pandas `ewm().mean()`, which is however non-symmetric, i.e. it only uses the past and current value to produce a smoothed version of the current point. This naturally introduces a lag -- I'm looking for a version that is symmetric and thus lag-free. Symmetric smoothing should also introduce less boundary artifacts at the start of the time series.

Example code showcasing the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(1, 4, 1000)
y = pd.Series(t**2 + 0.5 *np.sin(100*t), index=t)

plt.plot(t, y, label='original')
plt.plot(t, y.ewm(halflife=40).mean(), label='ewma')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[Plot showing the problem with the smoothed signal lagging behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEBGe.png)

Comment: why would you do a forward/backward filtering with an IIR? that makes very little sense, mathematically. What is ist that you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to smooth in a way so that points close to the current value have more influence without introducing lag, so the IIR property of the filter is not exactly what I am interested in. If you have another suggestion on what would be more appropriate, please let me know.

Comment: You may want to take a look at scipy [filtfilt function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html)

Comment: @dankal444 **noo** `filtfilt` *is* fw/bw filtering. What till-m needs is plain convolution with a symmetric filter kernel, nothing exotic like that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller of course, simple [lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) + removing boundaries would do. I just think filtfilt is more convenient as it does this cutting for you

Comment: @MarcusMüller "plain convolution with a symmetric filter kernel" sounds about right, but I need there to be some handling of boundary effects so that the resulting signal is not shortened.

Comment: speaking from a practical point of view: every finite filter that's symmetric (or anti-symmetric) has a constant group delay of half its length. So, appending its length (-1) in zeros to the signal, and then thrwoing away the first length/2 and last length/2 samples from the output gives you exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform a symmetric smoothing using exponential weighted moving average, you can take the average of the forward and backward exponentially weighted moving average for each data point, like so:

**Python:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def symmetric_ewma(data, halflife):
    forward_ewma = data.ewm(halflife=halflife).mean()
    backward_ewma = data.iloc[::-1].ewm(halflife=halflife).mean().iloc[::-1]
    return (forward_ewma + backward_ewma) / 2

t = np.linspace(1, 4, 1000)
y = pd.Series(t**2 + 0.5 *np.sin(100*t), index=t)

plt.plot(t, y, label='original')
plt.plot(t, symmetric_ewma(y, halflife=40), label='symmetric_ewma')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

In this example, the "symmetric_ewma" function takes in the data series and the halflife value and returns the symmetric exponential weighted moving average.

The function calculates the forward exponentially weighted moving average and the backward exponentially weighted moving average by reversing the data series using the iloc[::-1] indexing method. It then takes the average of the two to obtain the symmetric exponential weighted moving average. That should be what you're looking for :)